# Interesting issue with ScriptManager timeout value happens only in win2k machines

Tags: asp.net-ajax

When I set the Asyncpostbacktimeout value to a large value like 3600000000, the scriptmanager throws a timeout exception (it throws the error almost immediately after user action which triggers ajax request, so it is not timing out because the server is not responding). If I reset this value to some sane number like 3600 or even 36000, it works fine. AJAx content is getting updated in the page.

This weirdness happens only in windows 2000 machines and does not happen in XP machines

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Is ASP.NET AJAX even supported on Windows 2000? I thought .NET 2.0 was the last supported release there.

Comment: Sounds like we have a reason why.  And I thought XP was long in the tooth.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's worth checking.

Comment: Further, is there a real why you would want the timeout set to such a large number?  I only ask because your talking about a weird problem with a work around that only applies to a dead OS.  You might as well be asking why IE 4 won't run your activex control...

Comment: Well, someone else developed this and i am maintaining it now. I have anyway changed the value now to a proper value like 180 (3 minutes is more than enough for our app) since such a higher value does not make sense.
But still was curious to know why it fails ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

timeout must be int32 and the max you can set is 2147483647 as Int32.